# Take API data from XML and do another API call using Python3

Tags: python, xml

I've got XML API data from which I need to take a value and run another API call from it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>    
<result status="OK" host="systemmonitor.co.uk" created="2018-10-26T09:45:27+01:00">    
<client>    
<clientid>12345</clientid>    
</client>
<client>    
<clientid>67890</clientid>    
</client>
```

There's about 100 clients in this file and what I need is to be able to take the ClientID value for each one and run it through another API call (I'm assuming I can set it as a variable?)

How would I go about taking the multiple client IDs and running them through API calls to get more data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to extract the data and then feed that into a list to make your second API call. This post might help:
[Extracting text from XML using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691514/extracting-text-from-xml-using-python)