# Extracting items from xml file and make a dataframe with python

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I am trying to extract the following values from an xml file: 
`NAME, Mode,LEVELS,Group,Type` and after I want to make `data.frame`. The problem I having so far is that I cannot get `<Name>ALICE</Name>` variables and output data.frame format is different than I need.

Here is the some post that I used when I built my `read_xml` function

1. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xml-parsing-python/
2. [Extracting text from XML using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691514/extracting-text-from-xml-using-python)
3. [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

here is the example `xml` file format

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Body>
    <DocType>List</DocType>
    <DocVersion>1</DocVersion>
    <LIST>
            <Name>ALICE</Name>
            <Variable>
                <Mode>Hole</Mode>
                <LEVELS>1</LEVELS>
                <Group>11</Group>
                <Type>0</Type>
                <Paint />
            </Variable>
            <Variable>
                <Mode>BEWEL</Mode>
                <LEVELS>2</LEVELS>
                <Group>22</Group>
                <Type>0</Type>
                <Paint />
            </Variable>

            <Name>WONDERLAND</Name>
            <Variable>
                <Mode>Mole</Mode>
                <LEVELS>1</LEVELS>
                <Group>11</Group>
                <Type>0</Type>
                <Paint />
            </Variable>
            <Variable>
                <Mode>Matrix</Mode>
                <LEVELS>6</LEVELS>
                <Group>66</Group>
                <Type>0</Type>
                <Paint />
            </Variable>
    </LIST>
</Body>
```

I built the following function;

```
xml_file = r"C:\xml.xml"

def read_xml(xml_file):

   etree = ET.parse(xml_file)
   root = etree.getroot()
   items = []
   for item in root.findall('./LIST/'):
      values  = {}
      for it in item:
         #print(it)
        values[it.tag] = it.text
      items.append(values)

   columns = ['Name','Mode', 'LEVELS','Group','Type']
   df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns = columns)

   return df


    print(read_xml(xml_file))
```

giving me this output

```
 Name    Mode LEVELS Group Type
0   NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN
1   NaN    Hole      1    11    0
2   NaN   BEWEL      2    22    0
3   NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN
4   NaN    Mole      1    11    0
5   NaN  Matrix      6    66    0
```

the expected output

```
            NAME      MODE   LEVELS  Group  Type
1            ALICE      Hole      1      11     0
2            ALICE      BEWEL     11     22     0      
3       WONDERLAND      MOLE      1      11     0      
4       WONDERLAND      MATRIX    6      66     0
```

How can I get the expected output!!

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tag is `Name` in loop then set to variable and last add to `dictionary` values:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
def read_xml(xml_file):

   etree = ET.parse(xml_file)
   root = etree.getroot()
   items = []
   for item in root.findall('LIST/'):
       values = {}
       if (item.tag == 'Name'):
           name = item.text
           continue
       for it in item:
           values[it.tag] = it.text
       values['Name'] = name
       items.append(values)

   columns = ['Name','Mode', 'LEVELS','Group','Type']
   df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns = columns)

   return df

xml_file = 'xml.xml'
print(read_xml(xml_file))
         Name    Mode LEVELS Group Type
0       ALICE    Hole      1    11    0
1       ALICE   BEWEL      2    22    0
2  WONDERLAND    Mole      1    11    0
3  WONDERLAND  Matrix      6    66    0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import pandas as pd

def xml_to_df(xml_file):

  tree = ET.parse(xml_file)

  root = tree.getroot()

  data = []
  for child in root:
    record = {}
    for subchild in child:
      record[subchild.tag] = subchild.text
    data.append(record)

  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  return df
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).